How can i make hidden headers preserve their state in VS-code?
When I collapse or fold a header defined section in vs-code notebooks, to hide the cells within, and reopen vs code, the collapsed section expands, showing all content again.
Example of what I mean by a collapsed header defined section:

How can I change this behavior and make vs-code remember collapsed header sections?

related? https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168807

Possibly, I believe it may refer to individual cell collapsing, but I'll add a comment on github to help diagnostics.

WARNING: This no longer seems to work:
To maintain collapsed headers collapsed upon reopening vs-code, you need to change vs-code's configuration to make the header arrows always visible.
To change the configuration and make header arrows always visible, and maintain their state:

Inside vs-code go to file, preferences, settings,
search for notebook folding
set showFoldingControls to always.
"notebook.showFoldingControls": "always",

I don't believe that linking always showing header arrows with maintaining their state after editor shutdown is intentional or reasonable, and may be fixed in the future so it's no longer needed, but that is the case at this moment.
